# What is the distance that atoms can be attracted to one another?

Tags: electromagnetism

Was in a discussion about the fluoridation of water.  How close must a fluoride ion (in water) be in order to be attracted to the apatite ion on your teeth in order to form the bond resulting in fluorapatite (calcium fluorophosphate)?

Answer (score 0):

The distance between atoms in a solid is typically around $2\times 10^{-10}\ \text{m}$.

The distance in a water molecule between the hydrogen and oxygen atom is $10^{-10}\ \text{m}$.

The distance in a water molecule between two hydrogen atoms is $1.633\times 10^{-10}\ \text{m}$.

The distance between atoms in a molecule depends not only on the atoms but on orbital hybridazation, and the electronic and steric nature of the substituents.

Carbon-carbon bond length is $154\times 10^{-12}\ \text{m}$.

In your case the bond length for Fluoride is $134\times 10^{-12}\ \text{m}$.

But in your case you are asking about Fluoride and Apatite.

Apatite is a molecule, so you are asking about bond length between two molecules.

Now the average distance between molecules in water is about $3.1\times 10^{-10}\ \text{m}$. So in your case the distance needs to be around this to create a covalent bond between Fluoride and Apetite in water.

Comment: So if I'm understanding this right, a fluoride ion must be roughly 3 Angstroms away from an apatite ion on the tooth surface in order to bond.

I'm also taking that to mean that there is not enough of an electromagnetic attraction between the two that could pull a fluoride ion in closer to within that 3 Angstrom distance.

Would that mean that any fluoride ions left would remain in that state as the water flowed down your throat, or would they bind with something else (considering the reactivity of fluorine)?

Comment: Well yes, they must be roughly 3 Angstroms away to bond. That is the average distance between molecules. Now you are right, it is EM attraction that pulls them on average this 3 Anstrom distance, but it is EM repulsion too, that keeps them at this distance on average.

Comment: The way bonding works is that even without a bond, they can physically get this close, and then they start bonding. Bonding means that some valence electrons in both molecules start to exist as per QM at a certain energy level around both molecules (classically orbiting both molecules), and thereby creating an EM attraction between them. The reason why they cannot get closer to each other is because there is EM repulsion between the rest of the EM fields, the inner shells (so not valence) of the molecules.

Comment: Those inner shells of the molecules (which are valence shells for atoms inside the molecules) repel each other and so they cannot get closer then 3 Angstoms on average. Now inside the molecules, the atoms are the same way bonded by valence electrons, that start to exist around more then one atom, thus creating an EM attraction between atoms, and so createing molecules. Atoms though cannot get closer, because of the EM repulsion between each atom's inner shells.